# Spring Rest Controller POST request doesn't work with Ajax Json Array payload

Tags: json, ajax, spring-mvc

I am getting 404 not found error while sending post request with json payload . At backend I am using spring rest controller .

Please find the code below .

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/testEnvironment/update", method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> updateEnvironment(@RequestParam("ids") String[] ids, @RequestParam("name") String name) {
    System.out.println(ids);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And Jquery function for above rest controller :-

```
 function testing(){
        var a = [] ;
        a.push('a');
        a.push('b');
        var b = '23';

         var search = {
                 "ids" : a,
                 "name" : b
        }

$.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "api/testEnvironment/update",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(search),
            traditional: true,
            success : function(data) {

            },
            error : function(e) {

            }
        });
   }
```

Comment: In the `ajax` call the `url` seems to be missing the leading `/`, try `"/api/testEnvironment/update"`

Comment: That might be my typo error , but i am sure its not related to url . Problem is related to json payload and rest controller